# Webservice retorna pro SoapUI, mas não retorna pro PHP

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Estou consumindo um WebService SOAP e estou encontrado o seguinte problema:
O WebService tem duas funções. No PHP, usando a classe SoapClient, criei o cliente e consumo a primeira função sem problema. 
Mas quando tento usar a segunda função, esta me retorna um monte de erros sem nexo. Mas quando tento consumir essa segunda função usando o SoapUI, a segunda função envia o retorno corretamente. Minha pergunta é: pode ser erro no WebService? Mas se é, como o SoapUI consegue consumir a mesma?

Complementando, tenho uma certa desconfiança que o erro possa estar mesmo no WebService, pois quando tentei importar o WSDL do mesmo no Java ou no Python, a importação falha. E isso nunca aconteceu com outros web-services que já consumi.
O caminho do WebService é:
http://wscaixa.datasysonline.net/wsDadosCaixa.asmx?wsdl

Meu código PHP:

```
<?php

    $clientesoap = new SoapClient("http://wscaixa.datasysonline.net/wsDadosCaixa.asmx?wsdl", array(
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    ));

    $xml = "<cartoes>";
    $xml .= "<lancamento>";
    $xml .= "<pedido>XXXX-XXXXX</pedido>";
    $xml .= "<parcela>1</parcela>";
    $xml .= "<nsu>666666</nsu>";
    $xml .= "<valorParcela>36</valorParcela>";
    $xml .= "<valorLiquido>35</valorLiquido>";
    $xml .= "<dtVencimento>10/03/2015</dtVencimento>";
    $xml .= "<dtAntecipacao>12/03/2015</dtAntecipacao>";
    $xml .= "<dtLiquidacao>12/03/2015</dtLiquidacao>";
    $xml .= "<taxaAntecipacao>2</taxaAntecipacao>";
    $xml .= "</lancamento>";
    $xml .= "</cartoes>";  

    $param = new stdClass();
    $param->Token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $param->Xml = $xml;

    $resultado = $clientesoap->AtualizarConciliacao($param);

    // a funcao abaixo funciona, mas a de cima (AtualizarConciliacao) dá erro:
    // $param->Data '2016-03-03';
    // $resultado = $clientesoap->BaixarVendasCartao($param);


    print_r($resultado);

?>
```

Comment: Meu código PHP: http://pastebin.com/Er3NRekz

Comment: Erro retornado pelo PHP: http://pastebin.com/Up3mGp6N

Comment: Paulo você poderia adicionar ai no enunciado da sua pergunta o trecho do código  , imagine que alguém futuramente tenha o mesmo problema e seu link não esteja mais disponível para acessar.

Comment: string Nome, já colei o código. Grato pela dica.

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro parece que o token está sendo enviado nulo.

Comment: Sem o token verdadeiro não é possível reproduzir seu problema. O WS também não é dos melhores desenvolvidos. O WDSL deveria ser auto documentável e explicitar exatamente quais campos ele espera, e não uma string nomeada `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Paulo.

Tomei a liberdade de transportar seu código para o visual studio e consegui identificar o problema.

O erro apresentado indica que o token estaria nulo, e está mesmo. Se você olhar os parametros enviados, verá que você só passa o XML e não o token como é a definição do método. Mesmo passando ele, eu consegui a mesma mensagem de erro se você enviar um token no formato string. Para que funcione corretamente você precisa converter o token para string base64.

Em C#, a conversão do seu token seria assim:

```
var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] textAsBytes = encoding.GetBytes(token);
string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(textAsBytes);
```

Assim, quando você for chamar, você chama:
cliente.AtualizarConciliacao(base64String, docxml);

A mensagem de erro vai ocorrer, mas agora será indicando "Token inválido.", que é uma mensagem padrão do webservice na validação do token.

Pelo que li na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php) do PHP, o comando para você seria:

```
(...)   
$tokenBase64 = base64_encode($token);
$resultado = $clientesoap->AtualizarConciliacao($tokenBase64, $xml);
```

Espero que ajude.
Abs

Comment: Andre, até tentei a sua solução, mas não deu certo. Mas eu imaginei que a maneira que estou enviando o token não está incorreta, pois a outra função funciona, mandando o token da mesma maneira:
$param->Token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$param->Data '2016-03-03';
$resultado = $clientesoap->BaixarVendasCartao($param);

Comment: Andre Mesquita, outra coisa: se você reparar na mensagem de erro que o PHP está retornando a mim, retorne que é um erro de C# vindo do próprio código do webservice. Inclusive diz o nome do arquivo C# do webservice do servidor: c:\tfs-csjs
istema\DTS_wsCaixa\Banco\Data.cs

Comment: Sim, o erro ocorre no codigo contigo em \Data.cs (Value cannot be null). Mas se você observar, o erro ocorre porque na hora que ele tenta transformar o token nulo que você enviou para string padrão dá o erro.
Ao meu ver há dois erros: O primeiro e mais importante é que o token não está sendo passado para a função. Se você abrir a URL do serviço que você colocou, verá, em XML, que a função AtualizarConciliacao pede dois parametros e não um. O outro é o tipo de string, mas se o token for correto, este não deve ocorrer.

Comment: André, veja ali no meu código que estou passando os dois parâmetros: 
$param = new stdClass();
$param->Token = 'aqui vai o token';
$param->Xml = $xml;
$resultado = $clientesoap->AtualizarConciliacao($param);

Tenho certeza que o token está sendo passado. Repare que ele vai dentro do array $param. Inclusive outra função do webservice funciona assim. O problema está nessa função.

Comment: Tenta: `$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; $resultado = $clientesoap->AtualizarConciliacao($token, $xml);`

Comment: E André, lembrando que a outra função funciona corretamente da mesma maneira:
$param = new stdClass();

$param->Token = 'aqui vai o token';
$param->Data '2016-03-03';
$resultado = $clientesoap->BaixarVendasCartao($param);

Comment: Neste caso, o ideal seria enviar assim, acredito eu:
` am = new stdClass(); $param->Token = base64_encode('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');$param->Xml = $xml;`